# Is there a name for an irregular polyhedron of fourteen sides?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I was given a popup calendar that is cardboard and has 14 sides.  The top and bottom are equilateral hexagons and each side of the top hexagon is attached to a trapezoid that widens away from the top hexagon and connects to a mirror image trapezoid that thins toward its connection with the bottom hexagon. The top and bottom hexagons are oriented the same with their vertices directly on top of each other. The resulting shape is convex and very loosely approximated by a sphere and all angles are less than 180 degrees. Each trapezoid is the same shape as all the others.

Is there a name for this irregular polyhedron?

Comment: I don't know a name for the full polyhedron, but it can be composed from two truncated regular hexagonal pyramids ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Generally speaking, a 14-sided polyhedron is a tetradecahedron.

Comment: @MPW Ye, but that would ignore all but the first sentence in the above description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a hexagonal [bifrustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifrustum).

[image: bifrustum]

Going off of Hagen's comment, I recognized that what he meant by "truncated pyramid" was properly called a frustum, and Google and Wikipedia did the rest.